# Log IPython output?

Tags: ipython

Is there any way to make IPython's logging capability include output as well as input?

This is what a log file looks like currently:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
# 2012-08-06.py 
# IPython automatic logging file
# 12:02 
# =================================
print "test"
```

I'd like to have one more line show up:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
# 2012-08-06.py 
# IPython automatic logging file
# 12:02 
# =================================
print "test"
# test
```

(the `#` is because I assume that is needed to prevent breaking IPython's `logplay` feature)

I suppose this is possible using IPython notebooks, but on at least one machine I need this for, I'm limited to ipython 0.10.2.

EDIT: I'd like to know how to set this up automatically, i.e. within the configuration file.    Right now my config looks like

```
from time import strftime
import os
logfilename = strftime('ipython_log_%Y-%m-%d')+".py" 
logfilepath = "%s/%s" % (os.getcwd(),logfilename) 

file_handle = open(logfilepath,'a') 
file_handle.write('########################################################\n') 
out_str = '# Started Logging At: '+ strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\n') 
file_handle.write(out_str) 
file_handle.write('########################################################\n') 
file_handle.close() 

c.TerminalInteractiveShell.logappend = logfilepath
c.TerminalInteractiveShell.logstart = True
```

but specifying `c.TerminalInteractiveShell.log_output = True` seems to have no affect

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's the `-o` option for `%logstart`:

```
-o: log also IPython's output.  In this mode, all commands which
  generate an Out[NN] prompt are recorded to the logfile, right after
  their corresponding input line.  The output lines are always
  prepended with a '#[Out]# ' marker, so that the log remains valid
  Python code.
```

ADDENDUM: If you are in an interactive ipython session for which logging has already been started, you must first stop logging and then restart:

```
In [1]: %logstop

In [2]: %logstart -o
Activating auto-logging. Current session state plus future input saved.
Filename       : ./ipython.py
Mode           : backup
Output logging : True
Raw input log  : False
Timestamping   : False
State          : active
```

Observe that, after the restart, "Output Logging" is now "True".

Comment: The solution appears to be doing this in a startup script, as described here: http://wiki.ipython.org/Cookbook/DatedLog (this was the solution provided in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836612/where-how-in-what-context-is-ipythons-configuration-file-executed?lq=1)

Comment: This is pretty handy, but in my case it only printed the code which has been executed, not the actual traceback.

Comment: This doesn't address the question which asks how to have the code output as well.