# Where / how / in what context is ipython's configuration file executed?

Tags: ipython

Where is ipython's configuration file, which starts with `c = get_config()`, executed?  I'm asking because I want to understand what order things are done in ipython, e.g. why certain commands will not work if included as `c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines`.

This is related to my other question, [Log IPython output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11833654/log-ipython-output), because I want access to a `logger` attribute, but I can't figure out how to access it in the configuration file, and by the time `exec_lines` are run, the logger has already started (it's too late).

EDIT: I've accepted a solution based on using a startup file in `ipython0.12+`.  Here is my implementation of that solution:

```
from time import strftime
import os.path

ip = get_ipython()

#ldir = ip.profile_dir.log_dir 
ldir = os.getcwd()
fname = 'ipython_log_' + strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + ".py"
filename = os.path.join(ldir, fname)
notnew = os.path.exists(filename)


try:
  ip.magic('logstart -o %s append' % filename)
  if notnew:
      ip.logger.log_write( u"########################################################\n" ) 
  else:
      ip.logger.log_write( u"#!/usr/bin/env python\n" )
      ip.logger.log_write( u"# " + fname + "\n" )
      ip.logger.log_write( u"# IPython automatic logging file\n" )
  ip.logger.log_write( u"# " + '# Started Logging At: '+ strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\n') ) 
  ip.logger.log_write( u"########################################################\n" ) 
  print " Logging to "+filename
except RuntimeError:
    print " Already logging to "+ip.logger.logfname
```

There are only two subtle differences from the proposed solution linked:
1. saves log to `cwd` instead of some log directory (though I like that more...)
2. `ip.magic_logstart` doesn't seem to exist, instead one should use `ip.magic('logstart')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The config system sets up a special namespace containing the `get_config()` function, runs the config file, and collects the values to apply them to the objects as they're created. Referring to your previous question, it doesn't look like there's a configuration value for logging output. You may want to start logging yourself after config, when you can control it more precisely. See [this example](http://wiki.ipython.org/Cookbook/DatedLog) of starting logging automatically.

Your other question mentions that you're limited to 0.10.2 on one system: that has a completely different config system that won't even look at the same file.