# python %logstart fails to store input results

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, ipython, spyder

[image: Proof]

I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53532655/logging-input-and-output-in-spyders-console) which led me to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11833654/log-ipython-output) in order to save ipython's input results(not to be confused input results with outputs; they are considered different things in ipython). The post's accepted answer is simply 'use `%logstart -o` in the ipython' and I follow the answer wholeheartedly, expecting it to work, but it does not.

Since a picture is worth more than a thousand words, I here present the picture that shows `%logstart -o` cannot solve my problem. The picture clearly shows that I used `%logstart -o` in the ipython and I played a file that prints a string and a numpy array. The string and the array do not show up in the ipython_log.py, which concludes either of two things.

1) `%logstart -o` is bugged(which I do not believe)

2) `%logstart -o` works but it does not accomplish my goal

My question is the following:

If `%logstart -o` cannot accomplish my goal, then what can?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is quite clear on the second post you referenced, but let me quote the important part for you:

> In this mode [i.e., the `%logstart` mode], all commands which generate an `Out[NN]` prompt are recorded to the logfile

Given that you're using `runfile` to run your code, not `Out[NN]` prompts will be generated and you have to use `print` statements instead to see your results (which can't be logged with `%logstart`).

So my only advice for you is to not use `runfile`, but to instead use cells, which are sections of code separated by comments of the form `# %%` and that you can run with `Shift+Enter`. That's equivalent to run your code directly in the console, which should generate the necessary `Out[NN]` prompts.

Other than that, I think it's not possible to get what you want, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I guess I have to stick with using logging module for efficient logging for a while now, since ipython does not quite support what I intended to do.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Sorry my advice was not helpful to you.